# Call a function from associative array by key JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

In JavaScript I have associative array of functions like this (like static field of a class):

```
functions={'name': function(){},'name':function(){}};
```

each function do something with array.
I also have method:

```
this.doSomethind= function(name, array){//class member
```

I need to call one of the functions finding it by name.

```
$.each(functions, function(key, value) {
                 if(key == name)
                    //here I need to call function with array as paremeter. It seems value(array); doesn't work.
                        }); 
}
```

Sorry if it's a dumb question, I'm just new in JavaScript.
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

If I'm understanding your problem correctly, you should just be able to say:

```
functions[name](array);
```

Instead of the `$.each()` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
value.apply(this, [array])
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as the information you have provided, you cannot access a parameter that is not yet in scope from the class methods. in your example spelling corrected

```
  //'array' is undefined / out of scope
  this.doSomething = function(name,array){
    //array is defined / in scope!
   };
```

Otherwise if the variable array you are talking about is defined in the scope somewhere, the first answer will work.